Any tricks to locating an open neutral?
Nevermind, resolved.  I'll leave it in case anyone else hits the problem.
Outlet (nearly 30 years old) destroyed itself with no apparent cause beyond the fact it had a heavy load on it.  The replacement showed open neutral to the unswitched side, the wire is floating around 20V.  I find the same voltage at one other outlet which is wired pass-through.
There are two other outlets on the circuit that test ok, one more that just testing it will be a fair hassle and I think there's a good chance there's another behind bookcases.  I presume I've got a loose connection in one of those outlets but they range from a pain to major furniture rearranging to access and it would really help if I didn't have to open up each one to try to find the culprit.  Note that the switches are accessible.
The layout doesn't provide much help.  The offender is the unswitched half, the other known bad is positioned at what I would have thought was the end of the run.
I know not to use them until the problem is fixed.  I am just hoping there's some shortcut to finding the culprit.

map out which ones are good and which ones are bad. The problem will be at one end of the wire that connects the two sets.

@Jasen Yeah--but the wire doesn't know that.  The more I've thought about it the more I think the wire branches at least twice rather than a daisy chain.  If we ever buy another house under construction I'm going to take very detailed pictures of all the utilities while the walls are still open.

@SolarMike Turned out to be in the 0th place.  There was a wire nut in the first box.

@LorenPechtel you what?

@LorenPechtel, can you add an answer how you found and resolved the problem? That would be the most helpful to others who have a similar problem.

@SolarMike I don't know why the original destroyed itself.  The open neutral was a wire nut in the box that got disturbed in swapping the outlet.  When I realized the wire split I decided to look more carefully in the accessible boxes before going into the hard ones.
